# sigma-algebra of Borel sets arising from the topology of open sets in real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers

Given that $\pi(\Bbb R)$ = $\{(-\infty,a] : a\in \mathbb{R} \}$, prove that $B(\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))$. 
If $\pi(\mathbb{R})$ is the smallest $\pi-$system containing the set $\mathbb{R}$, then what does $\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))$ mean ? Does it mean collection of all open sets open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: What is $B(\mathbb{R})$? What is $\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))$? What is a $\pi-system$? In basic measure theory, I have never heard this notation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_system

Comment: @AnalysisStudent  Thanks. Now I can try and answer this.

Answer (score 1):

$B(R)$ is the family of Borel sets in $R$.

$\sigma (X)$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $X,$ which is  also the intersection of all sigma-algebras that have $X$ for a subset.

In particular,if $T$ is the set of open real sets then $B(R)=\sigma (T).$

For $a\in R$ we have $(-\infty,a)\in \sigma (\pi (R)), $ because $Q$ is countable and $(-\infty,a)=\cup \{(-\infty,q]: a>q\in Q\}.$ For $b\in R$ we have $(b,\infty)\in \sigma (\pi  (R))$ because $(b,\infty)=R$  \ $(-\infty,b].$ So $(b,a)=(-\infty,a)\cap (b,\infty)\in \sigma (\pi (R)).$ Every open real set is the union of a countable family of bounded open intervals, so $T\subset \sigma (\pi (R)).$  So $ B(R)=\sigma (T)\subset \sigma (\pi (R)).$

On the other hand $\pi(R)\subset \sigma(T)$ because $(-\infty,a]=R \backslash  (a,\infty)\in \sigma(T)$ for all $a\in R.$ So $\sigma (\pi (R))\subset \sigma (T)=B(R). $

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by showing $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))$ and $\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Step 1: To show $\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$:

We know that 
\begin{eqnarray}
\pi(\mathbb{R})=\{(-\infty,x]:x\in \mathbb{R}\}.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, it suffices to show that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $(-\infty,x]\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. We have

\begin{eqnarray}
(-\infty,x]=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-\infty,x+\frac{1}{n}\right)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),
\end{eqnarray}
since $\left(-\infty,x+\frac{1}{n}\right)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $n\geq 1$, and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Step 2: To show $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))$:

It suffices to show that any $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $G$ open, belongs to $\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))$. However, since any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as a countable union of open intervals, it suffices to show that any open interval belongs to $\sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R}))$.

Consider $(a,b)$, $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Then, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
(a,x]&=(-\infty,x]\cap ((-\infty,a])^{C} \in \sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R})),\\
(a,b)&=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a,b-\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)\frac{1}{n}\right]\in \sigma(\pi(\mathbb{R})).
\end{eqnarray}